# Error 6 when injecting DLL using C#

Tags: c#, dll-injection

when I try to inject a DLL with C# into a java process (Minecraft specifically) I get an error "ERROR 6", I've been googling this error but couldnt find a solution. 
The program is run in administrator mode, and it isnt trying to load from an admin path. 
My code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Text;

namespace Launcher
{
internal class InjectionUtils
{
    public struct CTX_PROCS
    {
        public Process[] procs;
    }

    private const int PROCESS_CREATE_THREAD = 2;

    private const int PROCESS_QUERY_INFORMATION = 1024;

    private const int PROCESS_VM_OPERATION = 8;

    private const int PROCESS_VM_WRITE = 32;

    private const int PROCESS_VM_READ = 16;

    private const uint MEM_COMMIT = 4096u;

    private const uint MEM_RESERVE = 8192u;

    private const uint PAGE_READWRITE = 4u;

    [DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
    public static extern IntPtr OpenProcess(int dwDesiredAccess, bool        bInheritHandle, int dwProcessId);

    [DllImport("kernel32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
    public static extern IntPtr GetModuleHandle(string lpModuleName);

    [DllImport("kernel32", CharSet = CharSet.Ansi, ExactSpelling = true, SetLastError = true)]
    private static extern IntPtr GetProcAddress(IntPtr hModule, string procName);

    [DllImport("kernel32.dll", ExactSpelling = true, SetLastError = true)]
    private static extern IntPtr VirtualAllocEx(IntPtr hProcess, IntPtr lpAddress, uint dwSize, uint flAllocationType, uint flProtect);

    [DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
    private static extern bool WriteProcessMemory(IntPtr hProcess, IntPtr lpBaseAddress, byte[] lpBuffer, uint nSize, out UIntPtr lpNumberOfBytesWritten);

    [DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
    private static extern IntPtr CreateRemoteThread(IntPtr hProcess, IntPtr lpThreadAttributes, uint dwStackSize, IntPtr lpStartAddress, IntPtr lpParameter, uint dwCreationFlags, IntPtr lpThreadId);

    [DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
    private static extern int MessageBox(IntPtr hWnd, string text, string caption, uint option);

    [DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
    [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
    private static extern bool CloseHandle(IntPtr hObject);

    [DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
    private static extern uint GetLastError();

    private void MBox(string text)
    {
        InjectionUtils.MessageBox(IntPtr.Zero, text, "", 0u);
    }

    public void DoInjection(string dllPath)
    {
        InjectionUtils.CTX_PROCS cTX_PROCS = this.FindProcessByNameAndTitle("javaw", "Minecraft 1.7");
        this.InjectDynamicLib(dllPath, cTX_PROCS.procs[0].Id);
    }

    public InjectionUtils.CTX_PROCS FindProcessByNameAndTitle(string processName, string title)
    {
        InjectionUtils.CTX_PROCS result = default(InjectionUtils.CTX_PROCS);
        List<Process> list = new List<Process>();
        Process[] processes = Process.GetProcesses();
        for (int i = 0; i < processes.Length; i++)
        {
            Process process = processes[i];
            if (process.ProcessName.Equals(processName) && process.MainWindowTitle.Contains(title))
            {
                list.Add(process);
            }
        }
        result.procs = list.ToArray();
        return result;
    }

    public void eject()
    {
    }

    private bool InjectDynamicLib(string dllPath, int pId)
    {
        bool result = false;
        IntPtr intPtr = InjectionUtils.OpenProcess(1082, false, pId);
        uint num = (uint)((dllPath.Length + 1) * Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(char)));
        if (intPtr != IntPtr.Zero)
        {
            IntPtr procAddress = InjectionUtils.GetProcAddress(InjectionUtils.GetModuleHandle("kernel32.dll"), "LoadLibraryA");
            IntPtr intPtr2 = InjectionUtils.VirtualAllocEx(intPtr, IntPtr.Zero, num, 12288u, 4u);
            UIntPtr uIntPtr;
            // Write path of dll to remote process
            if (InjectionUtils.WriteProcessMemory(intPtr, intPtr2, Encoding.Default.GetBytes(dllPath), num, out uIntPtr))
            {
                InjectionUtils.CloseHandle(InjectionUtils.CreateRemoteThread(intPtr, IntPtr.Zero, 0u, procAddress, intPtr2, 0u, IntPtr.Zero));
                result = true;
            }
            InjectionUtils.CloseHandle(intPtr);
        }
        if (InjectionUtils.GetLastError() != 0u)
        {
            this.MBox("ERROR " + InjectionUtils.GetLastError());
        }
        return result;
    }
```

If anyone could help I would appreciate it dearly :)
Thanks in advance :D

Comment: EDIT: it is trying to load the dll thats inside
"C:\Viliant\viliant.dll"
The passed paramaters on #InjectionUtils.DoInjection are
"C:\\Viliant\\viliant.dll"
This function is called on formload.

Comment: Please edit the Question properly by using the edit button

Comment: Error code 6 is Error_Invalid_Handle so check all the handles you are using

Comment: @PawełŁukasik I found out the error is here  `InjectionUtils.CloseHandle(InjectionUtils.CreateRemoteThread(intPtr, IntPtr.Zero, 0u, procAddress, intPtr2, 0u, IntPtr.Zero));`

Comment: then check if the `CreateRemoteThread` returns you the correct handle - probably not, and then after it failed check what is the `GetLastError` - that's the real issues here

Comment: @PawełŁukasik I really couldn't find a way to make it work, I rewrote it and then it worked somehow. Thanks I guess haha

Comment: good for you. Maybe write an answer then with correct code and later mark it as an answer? for future visitors?

Answer (score 0):

From [MSDN Error Code List](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/debug/system-error-codes--0-499-):

> ERROR_INVALID_HANDLE
>
> 0x6

Before you call GetLastError() you call CloseHandle() twice, once on the thread handle and on the process handle.

To find the problem just check the returns from OpenProcess() and CreateRemoteThread() and compare against the info you find in the functions documentation on MSDN.

For a simple no frills C# injector, this is the code I like to use which includes some error checking and uses the managed Process::Dispose() method instead of calling the native CloseHandle() at least on the process handle:

```
public static bool InjectDLL(string dllpath, string procname)
{
    Process[] procs = Process.GetProcessesByName(Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(procname));

    if (procs.Length == 0)
    {
        return false;
    }

    Process proc = procs[0];

    if (proc.Handle != IntPtr.Zero)
    {
        IntPtr loc = VirtualAllocEx(proc.Handle, IntPtr.Zero, MAX_PATH, AllocationType.Commit | AllocationType.Reserve,
            MemoryProtection.ReadWrite);

        if (loc.Equals(0))
        {
            return false;
        }

        IntPtr bytesRead = IntPtr.Zero;

        bool result = WriteProcessMemory(proc.Handle, loc, dllpath.ToCharArray(), dllpath.Length, out bytesRead);

        if (!result || bytesRead.Equals(0))
        {
            return false;
        }

        IntPtr loadlibAddy = GetProcAddress(GetModuleHandle("kernel32.dll"), "LoadLibraryA");

        IntPtr hThread = CreateRemoteThread(proc.Handle, IntPtr.Zero, 0, loadlibAddy, loc, 0, out _);

      
        if (!hThread.Equals(0))
        {
            CloseHandle(hThread);
        }
        else return false;
    }
    else return false;

    //this will CloseHandle automatically using the managed method
    proc.Dispose();
    return true;
}
```

Make sure to run as admin and pinvoke any missing definitions.